# What does "to begin with the more obscure as a way to build recognition about the familiar" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> My strategy in this chapter is to begin with the more obscure as a way to build
>   recognition about the familiar.

There is not a single word in the above sentence that I do not know; nonetheless, the meaning of the whole sentence is unclear. What does it mean?

Comment: Treat "the more obscure" and "the familiar" as noun phrases and it should be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will begin this chapter by analysing an obscure situation. When I have explored the concepts in this unfamiliar context I will then show how to apply the ideas to a more familiar situation.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! Is it logical though? I mean typically we first explain familiar examples and cases and then go to explicating more obscure, difficult cases.

Comment: I agree that the approach did surprise me. But as a teacher I recognise that one should always consider what sequence of presentation may most help the student. Possibly the underlying principles might be less easy to draw out when dealing with a familiar situation.